# Definition of rotation moment in a vertical surface during forced precession of a gyroscope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes, precession

[image: Forces in gyroscope by AT]

[image: Gyroscope legends]

I have the following assumption:

Moment of gyroscope flywheel created by gravity force:

[image]

Rotation moment of natural precession due to gravity forces:

[image]

Since the flywheel does not drop:

[image]

However, when we try to increase or decrease the angular velocity [image: ω_p] of precession rotation, the lever with flywheel goes up or down.
I am trying to understand how to define the rotation moment in a vertical surface during forced precession of a gyroscope.
Can we assume that the following equation will be valid to define the rotation moment[image], appearing in the vertical surface during forced precession of a gyroscope?

[image]

If yes, then the following should be fair:

[image]

Taking into account that

[image]

Is this interpretation above correct?
I have also tried to simulate the calculations with some data, considering that gyroscope can be assembled from old computer HDD where the maximum speed of discs will be 15000 RPM, the speed of whole gyroscope rotation can reach at least 2000 RPM and the total weight of system will be around 0.3 kg. The data collected in the following table, calculated in excel:

[image: Definition of rotation moment in a vertical surface during forced precession of a gyroscope]

Comment: $m_B$ is scalar so $m_B\times$ is not defined? What is given and what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Eli - I cringe seeing $\times$ used as both a scalar product and a cross product.

Comment: @Eli, I am trying to formalize the possiblity to calculate Mv, knowing these: m(B), m(A), r, R, J(B), J(A), ω(B), ω(A). In this case ω(A) = ω(p) + ω(f)

Comment: Besides the notation being super confusing, please remember that each body only has one motion and you can't pick and choose which rotation applies. Work out the kinematics to find the motion of the center of mass, and the motion about the center of mass and then apply the equations of motion. To check you have the correct result, check that $F = m a$ and $M = J \dot{\omega} + \omega \times (J \omega)$ balance out.